# List of theorems regarding dimension of vector spaces and maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am studying for the exam next week and I am reviewing dimensions.
So far I put together:

- If $f:V \to W$ is a linear mapping between finite-dimensional vector spaces, then
  \begin{gather*}
  \dim(V) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\operatorname{im}(f)), (1)\\
  \dim(\hom(V, W)) = \dim(V) \cdot \dim(W). (2)
  \end{gather*}
- For linear subspaces $U_1$ and $U_2$:
  $$
  \dim(U_1 + U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) - \dim(U_1\cap U_2).
  $$
- Direct sum $\oplus$:
  $$
  \dim(U_1 \oplus U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2).
  $$
- Quotient spaces: If $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then
  $$
  \dim(V/U) + \dim(U) = \dim(V).
  $$
- Dual space: for a finite dimensional space $V$  (special case of $(2)$)
  $$ dim(V) = dim(V*)  
  $$

Are there other theorems for dimensions?

Comment: All this is true for *finite* dimensions, of course...

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional then $f$ is injective iff $dim(im(f))=dim (V).$ (A useful corollary to your first equation.)... If $dim (V)=n$ and $B$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ there is  a set $C$ with $B\subset C\subset V $ where $C$ is linearly independent and has $n$ members....

Comment: @Chiray: While LaTeXifying the operators, I took the liberty of re-titling your question. If this doesn't match your intent, please revert or otherwise edit.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you, I couldnt find the symbol for the direct sum. @ user254665 I didn't know that corollary, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you have more than you need here.  The "direct sum" equation is just a special case of the sum equation above it, and the quotient space equation is just a special case of the rank-nullity theorem at the top (take $f : V \to V/U$ to be the projection map).

Comment: I know, they are all related in some ways, except the one for the hom(V, W), I think. Do you know any other equations?